# Regex to match paths

Tags: php, regex

```
    $this->path = trim($path, '/');

    while (strpos($this->path, '//') !== false)
        $this->path = str_replace('//', '/', $this->path);

    $arraypath = ($this->path == '' ? [] : explode('/', $this->path));

    $c_arraypath = count($arraypath);
    $this->regex .= '/^';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $c_arraypath; $i++)
    {
        if ($arraypath[$i] == '*')
        {
            $this->regex .= '(?:\/(.+))?';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($i > 0)
            {
                $this->regex .= '\/';
            }

            if ($arraypath[$i] == '?')
            {
                $this->regex .= '([^\/]+)';
            }
            else
            {
                $this->regex .= preg_quote(strtolower($arraypath[$i]), '/');
            }
        }
    }
    $this->regex .= '$/i';
```

https://github.com/Manhim/Cervo/blob/dev-2.4.x/library/Cervo/Libraries/RouterPath.php (line 79-112)

The point of this code is to save a regex that can be used to match against the current path and to get the arguments in the path.

The rules are:

- Strings must be matches as-is (case insensitive)
- The ? sign matches exactly 1 argument
- The * sign matches 0 or more arguments
- Only the arguments must be matched
- An empty path must match only an empty path
- If there is only a *, it must match everything
- Preferably doesn't match any starting or ending slashes (/), but it will explode the content in an array and it's possible to add a `trim()` worst case

EX: Test/?/?/*

This will match Test/Arg1/Arg2, Test/Arg1/Arg2/Arg3, ... but it won't match Test/Arg1 or Test.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work on every cases and I would like to come up with a better solution for this.

So far there is 2 ways of fixing this issue:

- Either I add pattern matching code without using regex
- I find a solution using regex

Unfortunately it seems like regex isn't my strength and I would like to know if such things already exists (?), or if it's even doable in regex.

Comment: Your example can be solved using `^Test/[^/]/[^/]/.*`, obviously given that forward slash is used in the expression you'll either have to escape it or use a different symbol for the check: `preg_match('#^Test/[^/]/[^/]/.*#'`, $input)`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. The biggest issue is when we start mixing things together, like: Test/?/*/?/Test2/*/?/*/Test3/*/?/? and then things starts to get a bit complicated.

I know that "This isn't all that logical", but I would like to be able to handle any situations with this code.

Comment: Although I'll keep in note to change the matching character to #, would be more easy to work with than escaping everything.

Comment: What should `*` be, and what should `?` be in your representation? In a regex `.*` represents anything(`.` = anything, `*` = any number of the proceeding) while `[^/]+` represents one or more characters that are not forward slashes(good for matching a directory).

Comment: Like stated in the rules, * is a character that should matches 0 or more nodes. ? should match exactly 1 node. (While a node is a string between each / in the URL/path).

The goal is to "transform" those characters into regex in order to ease the routing.

Add: The only thing I can be sure about the path that will be matched against is that there is no starting or ending slashes (/).